# Paste eventListener not working in condenteditable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to handle the paste eventListener using jquery, but it seems like I cannot make it work.

Below is my code:

```
function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}
```

If I do this instead, it works perfectly fine.

```
document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

But if I do this, it stops working.

```
$('#editableDiv').on('paste',function(event){
handlePaste(event);
});
```

Which part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jquery event handler, you should pass `originalEvent` property of the `event` object:

```
$('#editableDiv').on('paste',function(event){
  handlePaste(event.originalEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handlePaste(e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    console.log(clipboardData)
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}

$(document).on('paste', '#editableDiv', function (e) {

handlePaste(e.originalEvent)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```